# Spark Streaming Task not serializable

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, amazon-kinesis

I am using zeppelin to run a streaming job.

The below code throws the following error -

Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: Object of org.apache.spark.streaming.kinesis.KinesisInputDStream is being serialized  possibly as a part of closure of an RDD operation. This is because  the DStream object is being referred to from within the closure.  Please rewrite the RDD operation inside this DStream to avoid this.  This has been enforced to avoid bloating of Spark tasks  with unnecessary objects.
Serialization stack:

> ```
> val v = kinesisStream 
> .map(x => { 
>
>        // function defined within map, this one works
>           def transform_iso_timestamp3 (event_type:String,ts:String):String = {
>
>               event_type match{
>                      case "low_balance" => ts.replace("T","").stripMargin.substring(0,19)
>                      case _ =>  ts.replace("T", " ").stripMargin.substring(0,16)+":00"
>                }
>            }   
>
>           JSON.parseFull(new String(x)) match {
>
>              case Some(a:Map[String,Any]) => (a("event_type").toString,transform_iso_timestamp2(a("event_type").toString,a("time").toString),1)
>
>              case _ => ("FAIL","2017-10-10 00:00:00",1)} 
>            }
>  ).map(r => Counts(r._1,r._2,r._3))
> ```

The only function I am using from outside the map closure is
**transform_iso_timestamp2**

its a simple function.

```
def transform_iso_timestamp2(event_type:String,ts:String):String = {

event_type match{
        case "low_balance" => ts.replace("T", " ").stripMargin.substring(0,19)
        case _ =>  ts.replace("T", " ").stripMargin.substring(0,16)+":00"
    }
}
```

I want to understand why this is not serializable?. Its not holding a reference to something outside itself.

Note that If I use the function **transform_iso_timestamp3** defined within the map then it works.

If I create simple scala object containing **transform_iso_timestamp2** , package into jar and then import that into my code then it works without a glitch.

Aoother way to make this work is to use transform instead of map on the DStream . I am not sure why that works.

Comment: Why is a function defined in a map?

Comment: If I use the function defined in the map then it works. as its not outside the map closure.

Comment: It's not easy to understand your first block code, could you indent and close parentheses? It will be easy to help you.

Comment: It does not need to be redefined for each `x` element. It should work if you move it out.